# Bootstrap tab content goes down

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a big problem with my Bootstrap tab-pane content.

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified">
  <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#masery1">Mastery Page 1</a></li>
  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#masery2">Mastery Page 2</a></li>
  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#masery3">Mastery Page 3</a></li>
  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#masery4">Mastery Page 4</a></li>
  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#masery5">Mastery Page 5</a></li>
  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#masery5">Mastery Page 6</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="masery1" class="tab-pane fade in active">
    <h1>Show the last 10 Games</h1>
</div>

<div id="masery2" class="tab-pane fade ">
    <h1>Show the last 10 Games</h1>
</div>
<div id="masery3" class="tab-pane fade">
    <h1>Show the last 10 Games</h1>
</div>
<div id="masery4" class="tab-pane fade">
    <h1>Show the last 10 Games</h1>
</div>
<div id="masery5" class="tab-pane fade">
    <h1>Show the last 10 Games</h1>
</div>
```

The Content goes on every tab a bit more down.
So #mastery1 looks fine but #mastery2's content is 200px lower then #mastery1 etc etc.
I don't understand why. I check every `<div>`.

You can see it here on the "Mastery Tab": https://lolstats.org/HORNETDanny/euw

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're missing a div for your mastery tabs. Wrap the mastery divs in a new div using tab-content.

```
<div class="tab-content">
    <div id="masery1" class="tab-pane fade in active">
         <h1>Show the last 10 Games</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="masery2" class="tab-pane fade ">
         <h1>Show the last 10 Games</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="masery3" class="tab-pane fade">
        <h1>Show the last 10 Games</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="masery4" class="tab-pane fade">
        <h1>Show the last 10 Games</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="masery5" class="tab-pane fade">
        <h1>Show the last 10 Games</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

This applies the following CSS rule:

```
.tab-content>.tab-pane {
    display: none;
}
```

Since divs have height, each div was taking up space on the page. Setting them to `display: none`, gives them no height. When a selected div has the `active` css class, the following rule is applied overriding the `display none`.

```
.tab-content>.active {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: @JustDanny You are welcome. P.S. You spelled "mastery" wrong in your div IDs.  :)

Answer (score 2):

Try wrapping your divs for each tab (with class of `tab-pane`) in a `div` with `class="tab-content"` such as:

```
    <div class="tab-content">
      <div id="mastery1" class="tab-pane fade">
        <h1>Show the last 10 Games</h1>
      <div>
      <!-- more tab content -->
    </div>
```

See the Bootstrap document for tabs here: https://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#markup

Answer (score 2):

Also it is worth noting that for some magic reason flex doesn't like tab-pane class so if you want to have flex conatiner inside tab you have to do this like:

```
<div class="tab-pane fade" id="home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="1-tab">
        <div class="d-flex flex-row flex-wrap">
        # something here
    </div>
</div>
```

if you put d-flex in the same div as tab-pane content is hidden but it still takes space that's why it is moved down.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting that abnormality because the first tab hides but still occupies the space it was occupying in the first place. The work around i did was to find a way to hide it whenever any of the other tabs is clicked and show it when it is clicked.

In your HTML add the [class] property to your tags like this

```
<div id="masery1" class="tab-pane fade in active" [class]="hideFirst" >
<h1>Show the last 10 Games</h1>
</div>
```

Then add the click event to your tabs title like this

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified">
<li class="active" (onclick)="clickTab(1)"><a data-toggle="tab" 
href="#masery1">Mastery Page 1</a></li>
<li (onclick)="clickTab(2)"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#masery2">Mastery Page 2</a> 
</li>
<li (onclick)="clickTab(3)"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#masery3">Mastery Page 3</a> 
</li>
<li (onclick)="clickTab(4)"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#masery4">Mastery Page 4</a> 
</li>
<li (onclick)="clickTab(5)"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#masery5">Mastery Page 5</a> 
</li>
<li (onclick)="clickTab(6)"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#masery5">Mastery Page 6</a> 
</li>
</ul>
```

then in your typescript declare the variable as follows

```
hideFirst: string = "hide"
```

Also create the clickTab function as follows

`clickTab(num){ this.hideFirst = num === 1 ? 'show' : 'hide'; }`

THis should do the trick...Happy coding :)